# Handling groups of categories/checkboxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, data-structures, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a form that has about 10-15 unrelated groups of checkboxes, each needing the ability to select multiple values. Creating a new table and HABTM association for each group seems like overkill.

For example, given a form for a Video table that should capture options on the following groups. The user should be able to select multiple checkboxes for each.

```
Emotions  
[x]Sad  
[x]Angry  
[ ]Happy  
[ ]Hopeful

Landscape
[x]Mountains  
[ ]City  
[ ]Indoors  
[x]Water

Industry 
[ ]Arts  
[x]Design  
[x]Technology  
[ ]Education
```

I've been thinking of approaching this with the following options, but none of them feel right.

**Option 1**
Create a Categories table, and associate each to a CategoryGroups table. Then store an array of of the checked category_ids into the video.emotions video.landscape and video.industry columns.

**Option 2**
Store hash/hstore values directly into the columns.

**Option 3**
Create table for each group of checkboxes. Then a HABTM association or join table for clip and options. Seems like the database could get cluttered.

**Option 4**
Create new column for each of the options. Seems like the table structure could get unwieldy.

Searching(probably with solr) is going to be an important part of the app, so the fields need to be easy to query and search. Is there a good way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to store Emotions, Landscapes and Industries as tags with [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). This way, you can keep your model clean while also keeping these fields easily searchable.

It seems to make sense too since these look like predefined tags that you are adding to this model.

Comment: Much simpler. Thanks!